# Who was the first person in-universe to call Superman a god?

Tags: dc, superman, history-of

Plenty of filmmakers and writers have embraced the idea that Superman represents a god descended upon mortal men. I'd like to know who was the first person in-universe that actually referred to Superman as a god (or something of a similar nature).

Comment: Which continuity?

Comment: @RogueJedi Any. I'm talking about the first instance in comic, movie, game, etc. where a character likens Superman to a god.